# Android Kizitonwose Calendarview onClick display next month

Tags: android, calendar

How to display next month in [Kizitonwose Calendarview](https://github.com/kizitonwose/CalendarView) by clicking button? Can't find any example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use method

```
val yearMonth = ....
calendar.scrollToMonth(yearMonth)
```

in your `button` `onClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

//Example If you click on a next button then the next month appears

```
    binding.exFiveNextMonthImage.setOnClickListener {
        binding.exFiveCalendar.findFirstVisibleMonth()?.let {
            binding.exFiveCalendar.smoothScrollToMonth(it.yearMonth.next)
        }
    }
```

//Example If you click on a previous button then the previous month appears

```
    binding.exFivePreviousMonthImage.setOnClickListener {
        binding.exFiveCalendar.findFirstVisibleMonth()?.let {
            binding.exFiveCalendar.smoothScrollToMonth(it.yearMonth.previous)
        }
    }
```

You just have to modify according to what you want, enjoy